# Change Set Validation failure : Custom Fields in FieldSets missing

Tags: change-set

Evening everybody,

I'm on the verge of breaking down for something which should be ridiculously simple.

I'm trying to migrate 2 customer objects from my sandbox to my production environment. I've added all the relevant fields to Field Sets, and added those to my Outbound Change Set along with the Record Types and Page Layouts. When I validate the Inbound Change Set on my prod org, it keeps failing. I've trying doing just one object at a time but it's still causing errors. I've got an error message displaying but I don't understand why this is an error.

In field: Account_Name__c - no CustomField named Implementation_Log__c.Account_Name__c found

The field referenced above is included in the Field Sets that are being migrated so I can't grasp why it's causing a problem. I did try and create the field manually in Prod with the same __c field name and try again but all that did was migrate the problem to the next field in the list.

Am I doing to have to add all my custom fields to my Change Set manually?

Comment: Using the Eclipse IDE, you can select just the object and have all the underlying new/updated fields transferred.  With change sets, it is as Daniel describes in his answer.

Comment: I had the Eclipse/Force.com installed but it's too difficult to get my head around quickly. That's why I ended up creating all the custom fields manually, all 250+ of them. One saving grace was I discovered the method via Schema Builder halfway through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to deploy the fields in addition to the field sets. Change sets don't resolve all the dependencies automatically you need to make sure you include new objects and fields added.

Comment: There is a button to locate the dependencies when you are creating a Change Set that might prove helpful. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_outbound_dependencies.htm&language=en_US

Comment: True, but it usually lists so many things I find it to be difficult to work with.

Comment: I can add the fields manully, that's not the issue, I was just trying to save time as there's so many of them. It seems that this is the way I'm going to have to go :(